# Ruby access words in string

Tags: ruby

I don't understand the best method to access a certain word by it's number in a string.

I tried using `[]` to access a word but instead it returns letter.

```
puts s 
# => I went for a walk
puts s[3]
# => w
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing will access the fourth character of String `s`.

Split the string to an array and then access the fourth element as follows.

```
puts s.split[3]
```

Note: Calling split without parameters separates the string by whitespace.

Edit: Fixing indexes. The index starts from 0. That means s.split[3] will access fourth element.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for the fourth character from the string since you start counting at 0

```
p "I went for a walk"[3]
# "e"
```

Instead, you could split the string into words, but don't just use split on itself because it will only split on a space, while normally you should split on all word boundaries with a small regular expression like this. Then you remove any empty elements caused by the commas and other boundaries.

```
p "I went for a walk, it was warm outside".split(/\W/).reject(&:empty?)
# ["I", "went", "for", "a", "walk", "it", "was", "warm", "outside"]

p "I went for a walk, it was warm outside".split(/\W/).reject(&:empty?)[1]
# "went"
```

Comment: instead of splitting on non-word and rejecting, you could just scan for words.

Comment: scan for words : `s.scan(/\w+/)`

Answer (score 0):

you can also simply do:

```
s.scan(/\w+/)[1]
=> "went"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    s = "I went for a walk"
    puts   s.scan(/\w+/)[2]

    =>  for
```

If you want to access the first word make sure you do it by accessing the index 0 and so fourth.

e.g:

```
s.scan(/\w+/)[0]
=> I
```